# Monitor directory for file creation

Tags: php, centos, monitoring, inotify

I'm using a VPS with CentOS 6.5, I need to create a PHP script that looks if a file was uploaded to my home/user/public_html/uploads and take it's name and save it in a DB (I can do this part). I do not know when files will be uploadd to that directory, it could be at any time so I'm wondering if there is a PHP or any other way (Linux) to monitor the upload folder for any file created inside it and run the PHP script, I found some articles on Google about things like inotify, auditd but there is no clear tutorials on how to do that. Can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be to create a cron job (can be a php script) and have it run through the directory and check the ctime of each file and compare it to the last time (create a timestamp of last run) the job ran and anything newer you can process accordingly.

Comment: A cron job can work but I need to react as soon as a file is created in that directory, that is why I'm looking into a reliable solution, i do not want to run the cron job every minute or so.

Comment: Understood... so this looks promising: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/

Comment: Yes when I follow the tutorial it works but only if i do as following : /home/user/public_html/uploads IN_CREATE logger " $# file was created"  this outputs the name of any file that created in real time in the folder but when I do add my php script it does not work : /home/user/public_html/uploads IN_CREATE  php home/user/public_html/uploads/test.php

Comment: put the full path to php: /usr/bin/php or whatever the path is to php